# Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, erc-20, smart-contract-wallets

MyCode Like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "./INToken.sol";
import "./Console.sol";

contract TransferCoin is Console {

    // 这个状态变量存储在区块链网络上
    address public owner;
    INToken public coin;

    constructor(address _coinAddress) {
        // 合约拥有者为合约创建者
        owner = msg.sender;
        // 设置映币地址
        coin = INToken(_coinAddress);
    }

    function trans(address _to, uint256 _amount) public {
        log("_to", _to);
        log("_amount", _amount);
        coin.transfer(_to, _amount);
    }
}
```

when i try to use `trans` function, the error: `transact to TransferCoin.trans errored: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance`.
but my account's balance is `99999596`.
Can anyone help me tell me how to solve this problem， thanks.

Comment: Could you please share INToken.sol source code ?

Comment: ```solidity// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0`
`pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;`
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";  
contract INToken is ERC20 {   
    uint constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000000000 * 10;   
    constructor() ERC20("InkeCoin", "INT") {  
        _mint(msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);  
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);  
    }  
    function decimals() public view virtual override returns (uint8) {  
        return 1;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: ```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
contract INToken is ERC20 { 
    uint constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000000000 * 10; // 1000亿
    constructor() ERC20("InkeCoin", "INT") {
        _mint(msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
    }
    function decimals() public view virtual override returns (uint8) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `TransferCoin::trans` function, you are calling `coin.transfer(_to, _amount)`, since your `INtoken` contract inherit from Openzeppelin `ERC20`, transfer implementation use `msg.sender`
It means that it's a transfer from your `TransferCoin` contract balance.

Please see differences between [tx.origin and msg.sender](https://davidkathoh.medium.com/tx-origin-vs-msg-sender-93db7f234cb9)

Maybe you should take a look at [delegatecall](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html?highlight=delegatecall#delegatecall-callcode-and-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your contract has enough `INToken` balance. Try this, https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L158

`coin.transferFrom(address(this), _to, _amount);`

Comment: thanks, but there will be another error: `errored: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: insufficient allowance`